# Unusual Intent or Firebase bug in my Android app

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-intent

Hi Stackoverflow community!
I am quite a beginner at Java and Android programming, but I am learning really fast. Recently I have got very strange error. I do not know what is this error about. There is absolutely no code or logcat errors. I think that the whole situation might be about ProfileFragment intent connecting FollowingFragment (which, in a strange turn of events is intentionally extending AppCompatActivity class). I think there can be also a bug with my Firebase usage but I don't really know. But here is an explanation of this error: After the said intent FollowingFragment displays nothing, just white blank space. There should be following users displayed. No crashes occur, no logcat errors also, generally nothing. What is wrong with it? Here is my code:
ProfileFragment:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "ProfileFragment";


    public interface OnGridImageSelectedListener{
        void onGridImageSelected(Photo photo, int activityNumber);
    }
    OnGridImageSelectedListener mOnGridImageSelectedListener;

    private static final int ACTIVITY_NUM = 4;
    private static final int NUM_GRID_COLUMNS = 3;

    //firebase
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference myRef;
    private FirebaseMethods mFirebaseMethods;


    //widgets
    private TextView mPosts, mFollowers, mFollowing, mDisplayName, mUsername, mWebsite, mDescription;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private CircleImageView mProfilePhoto;
    private GridView gridView;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ImageView profileMenu;
    private BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNavigationView;
    private Context mContext;


    static class ViewHolder{

    User user = new User();
    }
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

    //vars
    private int mFollowersCount = 0;
    private int mFollowingCount = 0;
    private int mPostsCount = 0;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        mDisplayName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.display_name);
        mUsername = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.username);
        mWebsite = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.website);
        mDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
        mProfilePhoto = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profile_photo);
        mPosts = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPosts);
        mFollowers = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFollowers);
        mFollowing = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFollowing);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.profileProgressBar);
        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.profileToolBar);
        profileMenu = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profileMenu);
        bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationViewEx) view.findViewById(R.id.bottomNavViewBar);
        mContext = getActivity();
        mFirebaseMethods = new FirebaseMethods(getActivity());
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: stared.");


        setupBottomNavigationView();
        setupToolbar();

        setupFirebaseAuth();
        setupGridView();

        getFollowersCount();
        getFollowingCount();
        getPostsCount();



        TextView editProfile = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textEditProfile);
        editProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating to " + mContext.getString(R.string.edit_profile_fragment));
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AccountSettingsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.calling_activity), getString(R.string.profile_activity));
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });

       // TextView mFollowing = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFollowing);
        mFollowing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FollowingFragment.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);




            }



        });



        return view;

    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        try{
            mOnGridImageSelectedListener = (OnGridImageSelectedListener) getActivity();
        }catch (ClassCastException e){
            Log.e(TAG, "onAttach: ClassCastException: " + e.getMessage() );
        }
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    private void setupGridView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "setupGridView: Setting up image grid.");

        final ArrayList<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<>();
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = reference
                .child(getString(R.string.dbname_user_photos))
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for ( DataSnapshot singleSnapshot :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    Photo photo = new Photo();
                    Map<String, Object> objectMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) singleSnapshot.getValue();

                    try {
                        photo.setCaption(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_caption)).toString());
                        photo.setTags(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_tags)).toString());
                        photo.setPhoto_id(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_photo_id)).toString());
                        photo.setUser_id(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_user_id)).toString());
                        photo.setDate_created(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_date_created)).toString());
                        photo.setImage_path(objectMap.get(getString(R.string.field_image_path)).toString());

                        ArrayList<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();
                        for (DataSnapshot dSnapshot : singleSnapshot
                                .child(getString(R.string.field_comments)).getChildren()) {
                            Comment comment = new Comment();
                            comment.setUser_id(dSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class).getUser_id());
                            comment.setComment(dSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class).getComment());
                            comment.setDate_created(dSnapshot.getValue(Comment.class).getDate_created());
                            comments.add(comment);
                        }

                        photo.setComments(comments);

                        List<Like> likesList = new ArrayList<Like>();
                        for (DataSnapshot dSnapshot : singleSnapshot
                                .child(getString(R.string.field_likes)).getChildren()) {
                            Like like = new Like();
                            like.setUser_id(dSnapshot.getValue(Like.class).getUser_id());
                            likesList.add(like);
                        }
                        photo.setLikes(likesList);
                        photos.add(photo);
                    }catch(NullPointerException e){
                        Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: NullPointerException: " + e.getMessage() );
                    }
                }

                //setup our image grid
                int gridWidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
                int imageWidth = gridWidth/NUM_GRID_COLUMNS;
                gridView.setColumnWidth(imageWidth);

                ArrayList<String> imgUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
                for(int i = 0; i < photos.size(); i++){
                    imgUrls.add(photos.get(i).getImage_path());
                }
                GridImageAdapter adapter = new GridImageAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.layout_grid_imageview,
                        "", imgUrls);
                gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

                gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        mOnGridImageSelectedListener.onGridImageSelected(photos.get(position), ACTIVITY_NUM);
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCancelled: query cancelled.");
            }
        });
    }

    private void getFollowersCount(){
        mFollowersCount = 0;

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = reference.child(getString(R.string.dbname_followers))
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found follower:" + singleSnapshot.getValue());
                    mFollowersCount++;
                }
                mFollowers.setText(String.valueOf(mFollowersCount));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
    /*Query userQuery = mReference
            .child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_users))
            .orderByChild(mContext.getString(R.string.field_user_id))
            .equalTo(getItem(position).getUser_id());
        userQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found user: " +
                        singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class).getUsername());

                holder.user = singleSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            }

        } */
    private void getFollowingCount(){
        mFollowingCount = 0;

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = reference.child(getString(R.string.dbname_following))
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found following user:" + singleSnapshot.getValue());
                    mFollowingCount++;
                }
                mFollowing.setText(String.valueOf(mFollowingCount));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void getPostsCount(){
        mPostsCount = 0;

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = reference.child(getString(R.string.dbname_user_photos))
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found post:" + singleSnapshot.getValue());
                    mPostsCount++;
                }
                mPosts.setText(String.valueOf(mPostsCount));
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void setProfileWidgets(UserSettings userSettings) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "setProfileWidgets: setting widgets with data retrieving from firebase database: " + userSettings.toString());
        //Log.d(TAG, "setProfileWidgets: setting widgets with data retrieving from firebase database: " + userSettings.getSettings().getUsername());


        //User user = userSettings.getUser();
        UserAccountSettings settings = userSettings.getSettings();

        UniversalImageLoader.setImage(settings.getProfile_photo(), mProfilePhoto, null, "");

        mDisplayName.setText(settings.getDisplay_name());
        mUsername.setText(settings.getUsername());
        mWebsite.setText(settings.getWebsite());
        mDescription.setText(settings.getDescription());
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    /**
     * Responsible for setting up the profile toolbar
     */
    private void setupToolbar(){

        ((ProfileActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        profileMenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: navigating to account settings.");
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AccountSettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * BottomNavigationView setup
     */
    private void setupBottomNavigationView(){
        Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: setting up BottomNavigationView");
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.setupBottomNavigationView(bottomNavigationView);
        BottomNavigationViewHelper.enableNavigation(mContext,getActivity() ,bottomNavigationView);
        Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(ACTIVITY_NUM);
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
    }

      /*
    ------------------------------------ Firebase ---------------------------------------------
     */

    /**
     * Setup the firebase auth object
     */
    private void setupFirebaseAuth(){
        Log.d(TAG, "setupFirebaseAuth: setting up firebase auth.");

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();

        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();


                if (user != null) {
                    // User is signed in
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
                } else {
                    // User is signed out
                    Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
                }
                // ...
            }
        };


        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                //retrieve user information from the database
                setProfileWidgets(mFirebaseMethods.getUserSettings(dataSnapshot));

                //retrieve images for the user in question

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mAuthListener != null) {
            mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
        }
    }


}
```

FollowingFragment.java

```
public class FollowingFragment extends AppCompatActivity{

    private ArrayList<Photo> mPhotos;
    private ArrayList<Photo> mPaginatedPhotos;
    private ArrayList<String> mFollowing;
    private ListView mListView;
    private MainfeedListAdapter mAdapter;
    private int mResults;
    TextView username;
    CircleImageView profilePhoto;


    @Nullable

    public View onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_following);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        mFollowing = new ArrayList<>();
        mPhotos = new ArrayList<>();
        getIncomingIntent();
        getFollowing();

        return mListView;
    }

    private void  getItDone(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_followrow, container, false);
        username = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.following_username2);
        profilePhoto = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.following_profile_image2);}


    private void getIncomingIntent(){
        Intent intent = getIntent();



    }
    private void getFollowing(){
        Log.d(TAG, "getFollowing: searching for following");

        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = reference
                .child(getString(R.string.dbname_following))
                .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found user: " +
                            singleSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.field_user_id)).getValue());


                    mFollowing.add(singleSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.field_user_id)).getValue().toString());
                    mFollowing.add(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                    username.setText(singleSnapshot.getValue(UserAccountSettings.class).getUsername());
                    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

                    imageLoader.displayImage(
                            singleSnapshot.getValue(UserAccountSettings.class).getProfile_photo(),
                            profilePhoto);
                    }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }




}
```

Comment: This `for ( DataSnapshot singleSnapshot :  dataSnapshot.getChildren()){` is wrong. Check the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write). If you expect a collection of items the snapshot will contain a `List<YourData>`. There is too much irrelevant code here and many things you're doing wrong

Comment: Could you explain more? I mean that irrelevant code and things I am doing wrong. As I said I am a beginner:)

Answer (score -1):

Add a Toast to check that the values are retrieving or not as -

```
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Toast.makeText(this, ""+ dataSnapshot, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: found user: " +
                            singleSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.field_user_id)).getValue());


                    mFollowing.add(singleSnapshot.child(getString(R.string.field_user_id)).getValue().toString());
                    mFollowing.add(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                    username.setText(singleSnapshot.getValue(UserAccountSettings.class).getUsername());
                    ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

                    imageLoader.displayImage(
                            singleSnapshot.getValue(UserAccountSettings.class).getProfile_photo(),
                            profilePhoto);
                    }
```

Comment: Toasting for debug? Isn't  it better to use `Log`?

Comment: Not even a Toast shows... Also in Toast.makeText line I had to erase "this"(because it was showing an error "Cannot resolve method 'makeText(anonymous com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener, java.lang.String, int)") and get there getApplicationContext, or other Context to at least make this error disappear